# angular 8 getting ActivatedRoute paramMap is including the queryParams on page load

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

My actual component and app is a bit more complicated. However, I just wanted to see if there's possibly something simple I am missing. I am unable to get the correct paramMap from the ActivatedRoute. This happens when the url also contains queryParams.

example url:
`www.example.org/event/d162f2c2-5bbe-414c-9961-60ab6f489dc5?blah=foo`

The console log below prints out the eventId as `d162f2c2-5bbe-414c-9961-60ab6f489dc5?blah=foo`

This only happens if I open the url from a link outside the application(i.e. an email or another website). Or if I copy and paste the url in a new browser window. Refreshing the page makes the eventId log correctly without the queryParams. However, why does it not work on initial page load from a external link?

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
        console.log('eventId', params.get('eventId'));
      });
  }

}
```

The route is insize a lazy loaded module. The main route has a route that looks like this:

```
{
        path: 'videos',
        component: VideosLayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard, CategoriesExistsGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () =>
                    import('../routes/videos/videos.module').then(m => m.VideosModule),
                data: {title: 'Videos Portal'},
            },
        ]
    },
```

Then inside videos.module is a route where the eventId is defined. VideosDetailComponent is where I am trying to get the eventId:

```
{
        path: 'detail/:eventId',
        component: VideosDetailComponent,
        canActivate: [],
        data: {title: 'Video Details'},
    },
```

This one is so weird. If the app is already loaded and I copy paste the url and hit return to reload the page, the eventId logs correctly. It's only when you open a new browser window without having the app already loaded, and copy paste the url. The eventId doesn't log correctly.

OMG, I think I have figured it out. In my AuthGuard I had some logic that used `router.navigate([redirectUrl]);` However since the url contained the queryParams, when i switched to `router.navigateByUrl(redirectUrl)` this made it work correctly.

Comment: Could you please share your routes setting code? Usually it is being configured in NgModules

Comment: Sorry this app is complicated. I am using lazy loading of a module

Comment: No worries, just want to see where and how do you define **eventId** in route

Comment: In the lazy loaded module, I have routes defined in there

Comment: please post the route definition, the one with `eventId`

Comment: Hi guys I updated the post with some route info.

Comment: Hmm, I think it has something to do with this AuthGuard that I am using. Will investigate further. When I removed the route guard, it seemed to work.

Comment: I figured it out, please see updated Post.